# При добавлении переменной Python в функцию выдает ошибки

Tags: python, функции

Когда я добавляю переменную `about_me` в функцию `info`, то python выдает ошибки (см скрин). Если эту переменную не добавлять, то все хорошо работает

Отрывок кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","help","info","hi",'hello','привет'])
def info(message):
    markup4 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    about_me2 = types.KeyboardButton("О проекте")
    mrk10 = types.KeyboardButton("Игры")
    mrk20 = types.KeyboardButton("Офисные продукты")
    markup4.add(mrk10,mrk20,about_me2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в главное меню",reply_markup=markup4)
```

Как можно пофиксить?
[image: Скрин 1]

Comment: Вы в отступах смешали табы и пробелы, используйте только что-то одно

Comment: я просто пробелы не ставил вообще, странно вышло

Comment: Значит у вас кнопка табуляции ставит четыре пробела, значит исправьте все старые табы в коде на эти самые четыре пробела например

Answer (score 0):

Пробелы оказались в табах, непонятно откуда